# Removing collections/shards/etc in SolrCloud/Zookeeper

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

Is there a way to remove a single or even all collections and their various associated settings/shards/etc in Zookeeper/SolrCloud?  I would like to start back with a fresh, clean SolrCloud, but I am not seeing any way to clean things up.  I tried running `zkcli.bat -zkhost localhost:<port> -cmd clear` but that didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SolrCloud Collections API proivdes support for this. Did you look at

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API

[Solrcloud delete collection bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579242/solrcloud-delete-collection-bug)

You can use solrctl tool if you are working with CDH Solr.

Comment: I no longer have the solr config and data directory available for shard6. It shows as missing in the cloud list in the solr admin page. Trying `/solr/admin/collections?action=DELETESHARD&shard=shard6&collection=collectionName` gives me `The slice: shard6 is currently active. Only non-active (or custom-hashed) slices can be deleted.` Setting up a fake shard6 and trying to unload it using the admin web ui (red button under core admin) will not unload it because the data dir is missing there are no collections. I'm not sure where the solrctl is supposed to be but am unable to find it.